# Symfony2 How to call a require_once function that is on other server (java bridge)

Tags: php, symfony, jasper-reports, php-java-bridge

Im trying to call some php code that I found in order to execute some java code to run a php jru jasper report.

Here is the code I want to run with Symfony

```
<?php

    function DescargarArchivo($fichero)
    {
        $basefichero = basename($fichero);
        header( "Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
        header( "Content-Length: ".filesize($fichero));
        header( "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=" .$basefichero."");
        readfile($fichero);
    }

    //Obtener Fecha de Hoy
    $fecha = time ();
    $fecha_partir1=date ( "h" , $fecha ) ;
    $fecha_partir2=date ( "i" , $fecha ) ;
    $fecha_partir4=date ( "s" , $fecha ) ;
    $fecha_partir3=$fecha_partir1-1;
    $reporte="Reporte_";
    $filename = $reporte. date("Y-m-d")."_". $fecha_partir3.'_'.$fecha_partir2.'_'.$fecha_partir4.'.pdf';

    //Llamando las librerias
    require_once('http://localhost:8080/JavaBridge/java/Java.inc');
    require('./php-jru/php-jru.php');
    //Llamando la funcion JRU de la libreria php-jru
    //$jru=new JRU();
    $jru=new PJRU();
    //Ruta del reporte compilado Jasper generado por IReports
    //$Reporte='C://xampp//htdocs//reportes_javabridge//reportes//report1.jasper';
    $Reporte='C://Dropbox//Apache Xampp//evaluacion_daci//web//reportes_javabridge//reportes//control_pago_estado_de_cuenta.jasper';
    //Ruta a donde deseo Guardar Mi archivo de salida Pdf
    //$SalidaReporte='C://xampp//htdocs//reportes_javabridge//'.$filename;
    $SalidaReporte='C://Dropbox//Apache Xampp//evaluacion_daci//web//reportes_javabridge//'.$filename;
    //Parametro en caso de que el reporte no este parametrizado
    $Parametro=new java('java.util.HashMap');
    $Parametro->put("id", 39);

    //Funcion de Conexion a mi Base de datos tipo MySql
    //$Conexion= new  JdbcConnection("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://localhost/probando_reportesphp","root","clave");
    $Conexion= new  JdbcConnection("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","jdbc:mysql://localhost/evaluaciones?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull","root","admin");
    //Generamos la Exportacion del reporte
    $jru->runReportToPdfFile($Reporte,$SalidaReporte,$Parametro,$Conexion->getConnection());

    if(file_exists($SalidaReporte)) 
    {   
        DescargarArchivo($filename);
        if(file_exists($SalidaReporte)) 
        { 
            if(unlink($filename)) 
            {       
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

My problem here is that require_once is installed in other server and dont know how to call this from the controller

Comment: Have you consider to use Jasper Server REST or SOAP API to simplify your problem? With web services you let Jasper all their Java responsibilities, keeping clean your Php app (only using calls to Jasper services)

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. I'll try it later when I have more time. Any good tutorial for the jasper server?

Comment: http://es.slideshare.net/mobile/marianolu/embedding-jaspersoft-into-your-php-application in github there are a lot of clients/wrappers ready to study and use, probably also for symfony2. With this method you don't need to use java wrappers or libraries, keeping clean and simple your php app

Comment: I finally executed a plain php page that calls javabridge installed in other server and generated the php and then redirect the user to the generated file.